# Error when I make a server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I make a server-side rendering, and when I open the web to view console I got 2 error messages.

**First error message:**

```
Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development
build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to
use the production build which skips development warnings and is
faster. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build for more details.
```

In my webpack.config.js I make sure I used this plugin.

```
plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false 
]
```

**Second error message:**

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the
checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server
rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the
client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which
works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering.
Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on 
the client or server:

    (client) id="27" >< option id="cbhlnhfolziayudi" da
    (server) id="27" >< option id="dktswsr" data-reacti
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two questions. I will address them one by one:

**React production warning**

Since you are using Webpack, you can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) plugin to eliminate dead codes in your build. This is necessary because ReactJs has lots of logging codes that logs messages in the development environment.

```js
plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
      }),
   ],
```

**React attempting to re-use markup**

This error is pretty self-explanatory. The rendered HTML code that is sent from the server mismatches with the DOM that is rendered on the client side. This usually happens when the component that you are using has asynchronous code that is not running on the server. If you are using Redux, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/redux-server-rendering-react-router-universal-web-app) to render the redux state on the server.